# Tensorflow text classification with 'int' and 'tf-idf' vectorizer

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, text-classification

My question is simple. I tried a text classification with both 'int' and 'tf-idf' vectorizers. I'd expect it would classify better with tf-idf but the scores are 0.65 for 'int' and 0.60 for 'tf-idf'. Why is this the case?

My Model:

```
MAX_TOKENS_NUM = 100000  # Maximum vocab size.
MAX_SEQUENCE_LEN = 40  # Sequence length to pad the outputs to.
EMBEDDING_DIMS = 100

model_simple = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model_simple.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))
model_simple.add(vectorize_layer)

model_simple.add(layers.Dense(EMBEDDING_DIMS, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(1e-3)))
model_simple.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
model_simple.add(layers.Dense(EMBEDDING_DIMS, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.L2(1e-3)))
model_simple.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))

# model_simple.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(MAX_TOKENS_NUM + 1, EMBEDDING_DIMS))
# # model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
# model_simple.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
# model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))

model_simple.add(layers.Dense(len(labels)))
model_simple.summary()
model_simple.compile(loss=losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy())
```

Comment: TFIDF scores indicate the 'rarity` of words according to occurrences across all the documents. `int` vectorization, which I assume is the process of encoding documents into a fixed sequence of integers (using a vocabulary of words) does not take into account the frequency of words but rather characterizes the words present within each document.

Comment: That's why I think tf idf should perform better. It holds more information.

Comment: TF-IDF would contain information on the frequencies, whereas the integer tokens would also hold positional information, which is important for most NLP tasks.